# Can't find my codeigniter website in my aws windows server 2012 R2 iis8.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, amazon-web-services, iis-8.5

I already tried calling a simple text document and simple and normal html/php website (no MVC) and there is no problem, but when i call the folder with the codeigniter website **111.111.111.111/CODEIGNITERSITE**

IN application/config/config.php: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://111.111.111.111/CODEIGNITERSITE';` , `$config['index_page'] = 'Inicio.php';` , (error log)`$config['log_threshold'] = 4;`(all messages)

IN application/config/routes.php: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Inicio.php';` , gives me (codeigniter i guess) error 404.

it should give me the right direction: **111.111.111.111/CODEIGNITERSITE/Inicio/login** (everithing works fine like this in my local pc (win8, xammp)) 
i read in a forum, someone that fix it "-changing index.php to index.php? in the config.php" but nothing different happens

and ,, if i enter the right  111.111.111.111/CODEIGNITERSITE/Inicio/login in the browser gives me the **server error 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

but if i enter the address including '/?' like this before the controller name 111.111.111.111/CODEIGNITERSITE/?/Inicio/login i can successfully go to the login page,,, but no further (i think because the rest gives me directions without the '?/' and gives the server error 404)

and add '/?' to the `base_url` neither works ,,,

the new thing i tried, was add a web.config doc and remove the index.php and i get a new error with the suggestion to enable the **directory browsing** (i did it)and just show me the folders i have 
someone have any other idea?
thanks for your help

Comment: are you remove index.php in your codeigniter project ?

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Inicio.php';` does not sound correct. Try `$route['default_controller'] = 'Inicio/login';` or `$route['default_controller'] = 'CODEIGNITERSITE/Inicio/login';` Also, if you are using CodeIgniter v3 then capitalization is important.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @VairaMuthu , i could fix the problem without removing the index.php 
and all thanks to the @MonkeyZeus idea just delete the .php from the `$route['default_controller']=`

that make sense since this $route  must be a reference to a controller,, -_-'

(additionally i cleaned all the crazy things i tried like : 
+return the **directory browsing** to disabled
+remove the web.config doc and bring back again the index.php)

if you still have problems with this try the step by step configuration from this youtube video: Windows 2012 - PHP Installation on IIS ( 8.5 )
 [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riqc-1B2H4Q)

thanks guys (y)!!!